# c++ class as a variable for another class

Tags: c++, class, arm, embedded, stm32

first of all, let me excuse myself for not being able to appropriately put into words what is my doubt, it might get clearer as you read the post. You might even jump to the /****HERE STARTS THE ACTUAL PROBLEM****/ part of the post and you might understand better. Again sorry.

I'm having a trouble when using an object of certain class as a variable member of another class.

I'm trying to write a c++ class which initializes a LCD16x2 for that purpose  I need to make use of another class named GPIO_PORT which allows me to initialize a given port as input or output as well as writing and reading that port. so by doing:

```
GPIO_PORT led('A', 5, 0);
```

I'm setting PORTA5 as an output GPIO.

by doing:

```
led.set_pin_status(1);
led.set_pin_status(0);
```

I can turn on and off the led respectively and it has another methods for handling GPIO (the GPIO_PORT class works like a charm)

So I want that my LCD class takes two vectors as parameters: Ports[6] with the letters of the ports that I want to initialize, and Pins[6] with the number of the given port, using the GPIO_PORT class defined before to make all the ports initialization.

So by using:

```
char ports[6] = {'A','A','A','B','B','B'};
int pins[6] = {1,2,3,1,2,3};
MyLCDClass lcd(char ports[6], int pins[6]);
```

I want lcd object to initialize ports A1, A2,A3, B1,B2,B3 as outputs using the GPIO_PORT class. For so, I used the following logic, I created a LCD16x2.h and a LCD16x2.cpp file.

header file:

```
//LCD16x2.h
#include "GPIO_PORT.h" //Library for handling GPIO ports


#define   IO      GPIO_PORT //this is just so I save typing time.
   
class LCD_16x2          //start definition of the class

{
private:

//PRIVATE DECLARATION GPIO_PORT OBJECTS AS VARIABLES
//I want this to be treated as global variables which can be modified by the methods in the class.
IO E_PIN;
IO RS_PIN;
IO D4_PIN;
IO D5_PIN;
IO D6_PIN;
IO D7_PIN;

/*this are the input parameters of the LCD class constructor */
char ports[6];
char pins[6];


public:

LCD_16x2(char ports[6],int pin[6]); //class constructor
};
```

.cpp file with header function implementation:

```
//LCD16x2.cpp
#include "include_files/LCD_16x2.h"

//public constructor implementation.
LCD_16x2::LCD_16x2(char puertos[6],int pines[6])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    ports[i] = puertos[i];
    pins[i] = pines[i];
}

//initializes IO ports at the given ports by the constructor parameters
IO  E_PIN(ports[0], pins[0], 0, 0);
IO RS_PIN(ports[1], pins[1], 0, 0);
IO D4_PIN(ports[2], pins[2], 0, 0);
IO D5_PIN(ports[3], pins[3], 0, 0);
IO D6_PIN(ports[4], pins[4], 0, 0);
IO D7_PIN(ports[5], pins[5], 0, 0);

//setting pin status to one to confirm the above code worked right (it actually behaves as expected)
/****HERE STARTS THE ACTUAL PROBLEM****/ 
//writing pin status here works right, the problem arises when putting  this in a separate method.
E_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
RS_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D7_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D6_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D5_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D4_PIN.set_pin_status(1);

}
```

So, if I do something like this in main.cpp:

```
char Arr1[6] = {'A','A','A','B','B','B'};
int  Arr2[6] = { 1,  2,  3,  1,  2 , 3};

LCD_16x2 lcd(Arr1,Arr2);
```

ports A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3 behave as expected, that is, they work as output driving led.

if I implement a new method (properly defined as private in the header file) for writing the ports in order to test it (in the same manner as it just was tested above) that is by doing:

```
void LCD_16x2::port_test(int status)
{
E_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
RS_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D7_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D6_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D5_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D4_PIN.set_pin_status(1);

}
```

so the .cpp file goes like this:

```
//LCD16x2.cpp
#include "include_files/LCD_16x2.h"

//public constructor implementation.
LCD_16x2::LCD_16x2(char puertos[6],int pines[6])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    ports[i] = puertos[i];
    pins[i] = pines[i];
}

//initializes IO ports at the given ports by the constructor parameters
IO  E_PIN(ports[0], pins[0], 0, 0);
IO RS_PIN(ports[1], pins[1], 0, 0);
IO D4_PIN(ports[2], pins[2], 0, 0);
IO D5_PIN(ports[3], pins[3], 0, 0);
IO D6_PIN(ports[4], pins[4], 0, 0);
IO D7_PIN(ports[5], pins[5], 0, 0);
port_test(1) //method for testing the ouput GPIO's  in the same manner as above.

}


void LCD_16x2::port_test(int status)
{
E_PIN.set_pin_status(status);
RS_PIN.set_pin_status(status);
D7_PIN.set_pin_status(status);
D6_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D5_PIN.set_pin_status(1);
D4_PIN.set_pin_status(status);

}
```

by defining this new method, the code bugs, it compiles and gets loaded to the microcontroller but It wont start running: the leds wont turn on nor the ports are being initialized as output. In fact if I start a debug session, the code gets stuck at the port_test function calling. I have been able to recognize that when port_test function tries to write to the corresponding pin, it is as if the pin were not initialized before.

Comment: *"first of all, let me excuse myself"* -- I'd rather not. Apologies can be stuck on the end of the question if they are necessary. As discussed in [ask], your opening paragraph should get right to the point, presenting your situation and scenario, or at least an overview. When you start with anything else, you are basically asking people to move on to the next question because it's not even worth the effort to click on this question. (The opening part of each question is shown in the list of questions. Use that to attract the people who could answer, not drive them away.)

Comment: In the constructor, you ase assigning variables to themselves. Use this pointer on the left hand side.

Comment: Of cource it doesn't work. You have `E_PIN` and others declared as a class field and declaring it again in the consturctor as a local variable. `E_PIN` in the consturctor and in the `port_test` are different instances.

Comment: @Eugene I'm sorry, I did not quite understand what you just said, Could you please be a little more detailed? thanks in advance

Comment: @I thought classes worked as any other variable. I mean, if the E_PIN variable were, for example, an integer instead of IO type, both the constructor and the port_test method would be able to modify its value since it is a global variable all the methods can access it

Comment: @ I need to create an object of the IO class which can be accessed as a global variable in the LCD class scope, so the init method can pass the required arguments and all the other methods of the LCD class can access the IO object and modify it

Comment: You've messed up scopes of the variables. There are globals, class fields, and locals - all different things. I think you should practice with C++ more on the solid ground (i.e. on PC) to get a deeper understaning of the language, before using it in the embedded applications.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was wrong. Did not notice class members are in English and parameters in Spanish.